# While Loop Performance : Extremely slow

Tags: linux, bash, perl

I have input.txt and parts.txt file as below:

```
input.txt
CAR*BMW*X1*BUMBER*PLATE~
CAR*AUDI*A5*HOOD~
CAR*MAZDA*CX3*QNX*DIGITAL~
CAR*BMW*X5*SEAT~
SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE~
CAR*FORD*FUSION*QNX~
CAR*GM*YUKON**~
```

```
parts.txt
BLACKBERRY
GOOGLE
NXP
```

Below bash code written in red hat Linux server and it is taking long time. Example i have input file that is 10MB in size and it took 3 hours to complete the process.

```
#!/bin/bash
segment=CAR
position=3
a=0
b=0
while IFS='*' read -r -d'~' -a data; do
    if [ "${data[0]}" = "$segment" ]; then
        if [ ${#data[$position]} -gt 0 ]; then
           data[$position]=$(shuf -n1 "/tmp/parts.txt")
        b=$((b+1))
        fi
    a=$((a+1))
    fi
    # and output the data
     (IFS=*; printf "%s~" "${data[*]}";)  >> /tgt/output.txt
done < /src/input.txt
```

```
output.txt
CAR*BMW*X1*BLACKBERRY*PLATE~
CAR*AUDI*A5*NXP~
CAR*MAZDA*CX3*NXP*DIGITAL~
CAR*BMW*X5*GOOGLE~
SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE~
CAR*FORD*FUSION*BLACKBERRY~
CAR*GM*YUKON**~
```

Explanation of code: 
for all the "CAR" segments in input.txt file i am trying to update the 3rd position in that line with random data from parts.txt file using shuf command. 
each field in line (input.txt) is separated by * and line delimiter is ~.

question: Can we improve the performance of above while statement ?
I tried below code to write the output.txt in one shot instead writing multiple times in while loop, but still this is taking time for 10MB input.txt file

```
 (IFS=*; printf "%s~" "${data[*]}";)
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

I searched online and everyone is telling pearl works good for these kinds of scenarios. Can we write this while loop using pearl commands and how?

Comment: `read` doesn't do any buffering; it can only consume *exactly* the data it will assign to any variables, so that a subsequent `read` doesn't miss any data. As a result, it only consumes its input one character at a time. If you are concerned about performance, `bash` is the wrong language to use.

Comment: I second the last line of that comment.

Comment: Can you explain the rule that applies to the last line of output, where you end up with `CAR*GM*YUKON**~` rather than `CAR*GM*YUKON*(random part)*~`? Also please clarify if the input file looks like `data~\ndata` (as example input.txt indicates) or `data~data` as your sample code and description seem to indicate.

Comment: Why do you need an extra "line delimiter"? They're already separate lines.

Comment: @DavidO @melpomene : Thank You for looking into the question. In the code i am checking if the data length in position 3 is greater than 0 then only update the element ```  ${#data[$position]} -gt 0 ``` .  no carriage return and line feed (CRLR) after delimiter ~.   example: data~data~  .  for understanding purposes i have posted like that in original question.

Comment: Also, you **never** want to put a command substitution in an inner loop. `$(...)` anything is bad. `$(shuf ...)` is worse, because not only is it a command substitution, but it's one running an external command. For the same reason, in a loop where you care about performance, creating a subshell to scope your `IFS` change isn't worth it.

Comment: ...*also*, don't run `>> /tgt/output.txt` inside a loop -- that's re-opening the output file every iteration. Move the redirection to apply to the whole loop: `done </src/input.txt >/tgt/output.txt`.

Comment: That said, big-picture, real-world? Bash is the wrong tool for the job. Personally, given a performance-sensitive text-processing task, I tend to reach for awk (if it's not an interesting enough problem to justify using [Julia](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/)).

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy .  I will research on replacing $(...) this. As DavidO suggested to keep the parts.txt file in buffer and read the values from buffer. I will try this out. Also i tried to redirect the output at the end of while loop </src/input.txt >/tgt/output.txt. But still no performance improvement as i originally posted.  So that is the reason i asked if i can achieve this in perl script.    thanks again.

Comment: Note that "please rewrite my script in-language-X/to-be-faster/whatever" is generally a question that's broad enough to be outside our guidelines for permissible scope.

Comment: ...going back to the `shuf`, thing: On the outside of your loop, you can add a redirection (after the `done`) like `5< <(shuf /tmp/parts.txt)`, and then you read `read line <&5` inside the loop when you want to read a line from that ongoing stream without all the performance overhead of starting up a new copy of `shuf`. (`5` as a file descriptor number is arbitrary; it just has to be more than 2 so it doesn't interfere with stdin/stdout/stderr, and it's a good habit when possible to use a value less than 10 for historical/legacy/portability reasons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working toward optimization the first step is to time how long it takes just to read the input file, and do nothing with it.  On my system that takes only a few hundredths of a second for a 10MB file.

So now we know the least amount of time it's going to take, we need to look at optimization strategies.  In your example code you are opening `parts.txt` and reading that file from the filesystem for every record in your input file.  So you're expanding the amount of work needed considerably. It would be nicer if you could keep the parts file in memory and just grab a random element from it for each record from your input file.

The next optimization you can make is to avoid shuffling the list of parts each time you need a part. Better to grab a random element, than to shuffle the elements.

You can also skip any processing for any records that don't begin with CAR, but that seems to be a lesser advantage.

Anyway, the following accomplishes those objectives:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use Time::HiRes qw(time);

my ($parts_file, $input_file, $output_file) = ('parts.txt', 'input.txt', 'output.txt');

GetOptions(
    "parts=s",  \$parts_file,
    "input=s",  \$input_file,
    "output=s", \$output_file,
);

my $t0 = time;
chomp(
    my @parts = do {
        open my $fh, '<', $parts_file or die "Cannot open $parts_file: $!\n";
        <$fh>;
    }
);

open my $input_fh, '<', $input_file or die "Cannot open $input_file for input: $!\n";
local $/ = '~';

open my $out_fh,   '>', $output_file or die "Cannot open $output_file for output: $!\n";

my $rec_count = 0;
while (my $rec = <$input_fh>) {
    chomp $rec;
    $rec =~ s{^
        (CAR\*(?:[^*]+\*){2})
        [^*]+
    }{
        $1 . $parts[int(rand(@parts))]
    }xe;
    ++$rec_count;
    print $out_fh "$rec$/";
}

close $out_fh or die "Cannot close output file $output_file: $!\n";
printf "Elapsed time: %-.03f\nRecords: %d\n", time-$t0, $rec_count;
```

On my system a file consisting of 488321 records (approximately 10MB in size) takes 0.588 seconds to process.

For your own needs you will want to take this Perl script and modify it to have more robust handling of filenames and filesystem paths. That's not part of the question that was asked, though.  The primary objective of this code is to demonstrate where optimizations can be taken; moving work out of the loop, for example; we only open the parts file once, we read it once, and we never shuffle; we just grab a random item from our in-memory list of parts.

Since command-line "one-liners" are so convenient, we should see if this can be boiled down to one. Mostly equivalent functionality can be achieved in a Perl "one-liner" by using the `-l`, `-a`, `-p`, `-F`, and `-e` switches(I'm taking the liberty of letting it flow to multiple lines, though):

```
perl -l0176  -apF'\*' -e '
    BEGIN{
        local $/ = "\n";
        chomp(@parts = do {open $fh, "<", shift(@ARGV); <$fh>})
    }
    $F[0] =~ m/^CAR/ && $F[3] =~ s/^\w+$/$parts[int(rand(@parts))]/e;
    $_ = join("*", @F);
' parts.txt input.txt >output.txt
```

Here's how it works:

The `-p` switch tells Perl to iterate over every line in the file specified on the command line, or if none is specified, over STDIN.  For each line, place the line's value into `$_`, and before moving on to the next line, print the contents of `$_` to STDOUT. This gives us the opportunity to modify `$_` such that changes get written to STDOUT. But we use the `-l` switch which lets us specify an octal value representing a different record separator. In this case we use the octal value for the `~` character.  This causes `-p` to iterate over records separated by `~` instead of `\n`.  Also the `-l` switch strips record separators on input, and replaces them on output.

However, we also use the `-a` and `-F` switches.  `-a` tells Perl to auto-split the input into the `@F` array, and `-F` lets us specify that we want to autosplit on the `*` character. Because `-F` accepts a PCRE pattern, and `*` is considered a quantifier in PCRE, we escape it with a backslash.

Next the `-e` switch says to evaluate the following string as code.  Finally we can discuss the string of code. First there is a `BEGIN{...}` block which shifts one value off of `@ARGV` and uses it as a name of a file to open to read the parts list from.  Once that filename has been shifted off, it won't be considered for reading by the `-p` switch later in the script (the BEGIN block happens before the implicit `-p` loop).  So just consider that the code in the `BEGIN{...}` block temporarily sets the record separator back to newlines, reads the parts file into an array, and then relinquishes the record separator back to being `~` again.

Now we can move on past the begin block.  `@F` has become the container holding the fields within a given record. The 4th field (offset 3) is the one you wish to swap. Check if the first field (offset 0) starts with `CAR`. If it does, set the contents of the 4th field to a random element from our parts array, but only if that field consists of one or more characters.

Then we join back together the fields, delimited with an asterisk and assign that result back to `$_`. Our work is done. Thanks to the `-p` switch, Perl writes the contents of `$_` to STDOUT and then appends the record separator, `~`.

Finally on the command line we first specify the path to the parts file, then the path to the input file, and then redirect STDOUT to our output file.

Comment: Thank You David. I will try the scrip given by you. Can i just add perl scrip given by you inside the bash script ? like perl -e "$(script)"

Comment: I provided a Perl script because the original question was tagged with 'perl'.  Anyway, you wouldn't invoke it as `perl -e "$(script)"`, you would make it executable and invoke it as any other command: `/path/to/script` or alternatively `perl /path/to/script`. You would also want to work around the fact that I hard-coded filenames as relative paths.  You'll want to modify it to be more robust in how it deals with filenames. But again, the question was tagged 'perl' for a reason, I assume.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` is your answer here I think:

```
awk 'BEGIN{while(getline<"parts.txt")r[++i]=$0;
           FS=OFS="*";
           RS=ORS="~";
           srand()}
     $1=="CAR"&&$4{$4=r[1+int(i*rand())]}
     1' input.txt >output.txt
```

Explanation:

`r[]` is an array that just holds all of the lines of `parts.txt`.

Input and output field and record separators are set to match the format of your `input.txt` file.

`srand()` seeds the `rand()` function (with time of day) so you don't get the same sequence of random elements each time.

If the conditions for changing the 4th field are met, the 4th field is changed to a random element of `r`.

The final `1` just causes the line to be printed, whether changed or unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

I absolutely agree that there are languages other than bash which will be both easier and faster.

Still, some days I can't resist a challenge. The key to making shell scripts run fast is to do as little as possible in the shell; try to find a way to use external utilities to work in bulk instead of line by line.

The following shell script is a crude example. It does several things in order to avoid looping in shell:

- The Gnu version of `shuf` provides the `-r` flag to generate a (potentially infinite) sequence of random lines taken from its input, instead of shuffling the input.
- The `paste` command does line-by-line concatenation of two input streams. (Unfortunately, it does not have a way of stopping when the shortest stream finishes, so you can't use it with an infinite stream. That forces an awkward extra scan of the input text in order to count the number of lines.)
- It's possible to encode the criteria "the first field is `CAR` and the fourth field is not empty" as a single regular expression. That lets us do all the selection and substitution with a single invocation of `sed`.
- The input file uses `~` instead of newline to delimit records, which is awkward for most Linux text file tools. We can use `tr '~' '\n'` to turn the tildes into newlines and `tr '\n' '~'` to turn newlines back into tildes at the end.

So here's the script:

```
# Count the number of "lines" in the input:
count=$(tr '~' '\n' <input.txt | wc -l)
# (paste) Paste together a column of random parts with the original input;
# (sed)   then substitute  what is now the fifth column with the new first column
#         if the criteria are met.
# (cut)   Finally strip out the column of random parts and
# (tr)    restore the record terminator ~ to return to the original format:
paste -d '*' <(shuf -rn$count parts.txt) \
             <(tr '~' '\n' <input.txt) |
sed -E 's/^([^*]+)([*]CAR([*][^*]+){2}[*])[^*]+/\1\2\1/' |
cut -f2- -d'*' |
tr '\n' '~'
```

And here's a sample run:

```
# The input is 500,000 lines -- about 10MB -- created at random
# from the short input data in the question
$ tr '~' '\n' < input.txt | wc
500000  500000 10498615
$ tr '~' '\n' < input.txt | head
CAR*BMW*X5*SEAT
SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE
CAR*GM*YUKON**
CAR*BMW*X1*BUMBER*PLATE
SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE
SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE
CAR*AUDI*A5*HOOD
CAR*AUDI*A5*HOOD
CAR*AUDI*A5*HOOD
CAR*FORD*FUSION*QNX

# The script takes a couple of seconds
$ time ./xform.sh > output.txt

real    0m1.517s
user    0m1.690s
sys     0m0.121s

# It seems to do the right thing:
$ tr '~' '\n' < output.txt | head
CAR*BMW*X5*NXP
SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE
CAR*GM*YUKON**
CAR*BMW*X1*GOOGLE*PLATE
SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE
SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE
CAR*AUDI*A5*GOOGLE
CAR*AUDI*A5*BLACKBERRY
CAR*AUDI*A5*BLACKBERRY
CAR*FORD*FUSION*NXP
```

---

Here's a version of the above script which requires you to specify the value of field 0 ("`$segment`") and the field number to substitute ("`$position`") as script parameters. It completely lacks checks on the validity of arguments, and it doesn't provide default values either. A robust script would do better. But it hopefully gives some idea as to how to parameterise the script. (That's done by building the `sed` regex using the supplied parameters).

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 is the string to match in field 0. It must not contain / nor any regex
# metacharacter.
# $2 is the number of the field to substitute. It must be > 0.
# Make the sed command:
sedcmd='s/^([^*]*)([*]'$1'[*]([^*]*[*]){'$(($2-1))'})([^*]+)/\1\2\1/'
# Count the number of "lines" in the input:
count=$(tr '~' '\n' <input.txt | wc -l)
# (paste) Paste together a column of random parts with the original input;
# (sed)   then substitute  what is now the (position+1) column with the new first column
#         if the criteria are met.
# (cut)   Finally strip out the column of random parts and
# (tr)    restore the record terminator ~ to return to the original format:
paste -d '*' <(shuf -rn$count parts.txt) \
             <(tr '~' '\n' <input.txt) |
sed -E "$sedcmd" |
cut -f2- -d'*' |
tr '\n' '~'
```

Usage:

```
$ time ./xform.sh CAR 3 > output.txt

real    0m1.519s
user    0m1.712s
sys     0m0.120s
```

Comment: wow, you have written the logic in 1 line. Before posting this question i researched and learned about sed.  It seems sed has a limit of line size and there is no limit if we use GNU version of sed.  so all my options are out with bash and asked for perl.  I believe you are using GNU version of sed. Your answers takes back to me to use Linux code and different ways in achieving the desired output.   Just curious where did you mention the 3rd element position in sed command ? would you mind explaining ```sed -E 's/^([^*]+)([*]CAR([*][^*]+){2}[*])[^*]+/\1\2\1/'``` ?

Comment: @skv: count the stars :-) A field is a `*` followed by any number of characters which are not `*`: (regex: `[*][^*]*`). The fourth field uses `[^*]+` in order to guarantee thee is at least one character. There's no problem with line length here because I've turned all the `~` into newlines before passing it through sed.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. I am very new to sed using the regex.  Still not understanding.  where in sed you are counting and how you are using that count to find the position 3 ?   the reason i am asking is i am trying to keep the position value as input variable, so that i can use variable $position in sed command.

Comment: @skv: I think this is not really the place for a regex tutorial; there are many. But the count is encoded in the repetition operator (`{2}`); the field pattern is repeated twice for position=3 because the first field has already been matched with `CAR`. I made a version which lets you specify segment and position as script arguments.

Comment: `$(($2-1))` means "the second parameter minus one"; arithmetic expressions written with `$((...))` are not required by Posix, but are implemented by most shells, including bash.

Comment: thank you. I am trying this code now. Will update the post regarding performance

Comment: i just tried the script and compared with old while loop. Just wow. Huge improvement. sed with regex completed in seconds and while loop taking more than 15 minutes.  Can we add audit to the script given by you as i did in my while loop ?  example: in my while loop i added variables a and b.  $a gives total segments with CAR and $b variable gives total elements that got replaced

Comment: also in while loop i have capability of further filtering the input.  example; ```SUV*FORD*EXPLORER*GLASS*SAFE~ ```  , data[0]=SUV && data[1]=FORD then look for GLASS field in the line if found then update the value next to GLASS if not empty with parts file.     to filter the line with SUV and FORD i can simply add second variable for FORD like ```sedcmd='s/^([^*]*)([*]'$1'[*]'$2'[*]([^*]*[*]){'$(($2-1))'})([^*]+)/\1\2\1/'``` , but not sure how i can then search for GLASS and position value next to GLASS

Comment: Yeah, if your requirements are more complicated, you really should look at doing it with AWK.